# CSV file to array of objects with different delimiter for headers and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, object

I have a CSV file where one header is Address and its values are spreaded among 3-4 cells but header is just mentioned once above the first cell.. I want to include all cells in header "address" while converting it into an object. Is it possible?

Comment: if you are asking whether it is possible, then the answer is yes. if you are asking how to do it, then please share your efforts and explain what was the issue

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have any built-in CSV functions, so you can parse the file however you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the length of the cell to achieve the purpose of displaying data, or the third-party tool you use supports the.